# java 7b55 - security warnings appear even though web start app is signed

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp, signing

I have an app delivered via Java Web Start that is signed with an official certificate provided by Verisign, and also a self-signed certificate that we have generated.  This is done because we restrict use of the official certificate for the build delivered to customers, but we need to have our test builds signed by a certificate to get the application loaded at all.

My question is; is it normal that Java 7b55 still shows security warnings for the self-signed certificate, even though the official certificate is present?  I would expect the official certificate to take precedence but it appears to be not the case.

Just wondering if anyone else has hit this or if it's unique to my environment..

Comment: *"is it normal that Java 7b55 still shows security warnings for the self-signed certificate,"*  No.  I'd have expected the JVM to block the app. completely.  A 'self-signed' certificate is not worth the bits it takes to store it.

Comment: Agreed self-signing is now useless, but I find that an unsigned application won't execute at all. I get the following stack trace when trying to launch an unsigned application: com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://<server>:<port>/<app>/<jarname>.jar
                at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
                at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
...

Answer (score 0):

Its shouldn't.... Unless you are using 1 keystore to perform all this.

Sounds like you are using your self signed keystore that is paired up with the private key inside and that you may have imported the official VeriSign one into the same keystore without matching up with the private key in the inside. Which is probably why the Official VeriSign certificate is not getting read during signing

Usually in situation like yours there should be two keystores. 1 with the self signed and another with the Official Signed certificate.

~DomSYMC